# I'm learning Python and why is a floating-point used in this example?

Tags: python, variables, floating-point

http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex4.html

There's an extra credit question asking me to explain why the floating-point 4.0 is used instead of 4.

I understand that a floating point is used for accuracy, but I can't fathom why it is necessary in any case in this example.

Comment: It's used for the 'space_in_a_car' variable... Just in case, if you like chainsaws, you may put 3.8 persons in a car...

Comment: Because the average number of children to transport is 2.6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There doesn't actually seem to be any need for a float instead of an int in that particular example. It could have an effect if you were to divide something by it, but that's not happening here. (And even then, it'd depend on whether you were using Python 2 or 3, as float division is the default in 3).

If you look at the comments below, zedshaw (the author) admits as much:

> **Михаил Груздев:** And why 4.0 used for space? Maybe it's drivers variable value should be floating-point?
>
> > **zedshaw:** Simply to introduce floating point as a little puzzle. Mathematically the exercise doesn't make much sense, it's just practice. Continue on for now.

Comment: Thank you for your most helpful post. I already knew about integers and floating-points and I have been wracking my brain around the idea that this had to be a float for some specific reason within this code.

Comment: You're welcome! And you're right, making that an "extra credit" question seems misleading to me, too. I've left a comment on the page saying as much.

Answer (score 1):

A floating point is used because in Python an `int` divided by an `int` produces an `int` ([integer division](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations)) which is not intended here. If you divide a `float` by an `int` or an `int` by a `float`, you get a `float`.

Example:

```
   4/3
=> 1
   4.0/3
=> 1.3333333333333333
   2*4/3
=> 2
   2*4.0/3
=> 2.6666666666666665
```

Comment: Exactly, space_in_car is only ever used in multiplication.

Comment: Yes. This is done to make the numerator a float for division later on.

Comment: Later on? Can you give me an example?

Comment: @Abhinav Sarkar - it is only used in multiplication later on, for calculating 'carpool_capacity'.

Comment: `space_in_a_car`: float, `cars_driven`: int, `passengers`:int => `carpool_capacity`: float => `average_passengers_per_car`: float

Answer (score 0):

This is because of something called Integer Division. Basically this means that if you divide two integers, the resulting number must be an integer. So, for example `3/4` would result in `0` and `4/3` would result in `1`. This is because `3/4` in "real" math would give you 0.75 and to turn 0.75 into and integer, Python truncates the floating point values and leaves you with 0.

The easiest way to fix this is to use 4.0 instead of 4. Turning the integer into a float and disregarding Integer Division because integer divided by float results in a float. `3/4.0` equals `0.75` like you want it to.

Answer (score -1):

Arithmetic with integer operands has an integer result.

```
>>> 3 / 2
1
```